# how can i connect django container to mysql container

Tags: mysql, django, docker

Hi i want to connect django - mysql in each container :)

i tried a lot of way but failed..

here is my mysql docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    platform: linux/x86_64
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: good-mysql
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
    command: 
      - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
      - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
    volumes:
      - /Users/Shared/data/mysql-test:/var/lib/mysql
    network_mode: bridge
```

i used mysql official image

and my django Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
FROM python:3.8.6-buster

ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# General Packages
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y libmariadb-dev \
    && apt-get install -y python3-pip \
    && apt-get install -y build-essential \
    && apt-get install -y libcurl4-openssl-dev \
    && apt-get install -y libssl-dev \
    && pip install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir -p /project/myproject
COPY ./myproject /project/myproject

RUN mkdir -p /app
    WORKDIR /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

and docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
    deepnatural-ai-api:
        build: .
        image: deepnatural-ai-api:latest
        container_name: deepnatural-ai-api
        ports:
            - 1000:1000
        external_links:
            - "good-mysql:db"
        network_mode: bridge
```

and i run `docker-compose up -d` each container

and access mysql container, run `mysql -uroot -p` its work!

but when i access django container run migrations its raise error

`"Unknown MySQL server host 'db' (-2)")`

my django settings.py is

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    '...',
]

DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'testdb',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'test',
    'HOST': 'db',
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'},
    }
}

ROOT_URLCONF = 'myproject.urls'

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD='django.db.models.AutoField'

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

INTERNAL_IPS = [
    '127.0.0.1',
    '0.0.0.0',
]
```

i have double check docker network, db host name, password, db name etc...

but django can't find db host "good-mysql"

please some advice thank you :)

EDIT:

when i run `docker ps`

[image]

and I tried change `HOST: "good-mysql"`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i solved my problem

i used `IPv4Address` of mysql container like `172.17.0.3`

i ran command `docker network inspect bridge` and check `IPv4Address`

and insert my settings.py like this

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
    'NAME': 'testdb',
    'USER': 'root',
    'PASSWORD': 'test',
    'HOST': '172.17.0.3', # <---- mysql container IPv4Address
    'PORT': '3306',
    'OPTIONS': {'auth_plugin': 'mysql_native_password'},
    }
}
```

and its work!

Answer (score 1):

```
pip install dj-database-url
```

###### settings.py

```
import dj_database_url

DATABASES = {"default": dj_database_url.config()}
```

and in your django container's config you need to add:

```
environment:
  - DATABASE_URL=mysql://<username>:<password>@<db_container_name>/<db_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try combining your docker-compose files:

```
version: '3.8'

services:
    deepnatural-ai-api:
        build: .
        image: deepnatural-ai-api:latest
        container_name: deepnatural-ai-api
        ports:
            - 1000:1000
        depends_on:
            - db
    db:
        platform: linux/x86_64
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
            - "3307:3306"
        environment:
            - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=test
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=testdb
        command: 
            - --character-set-server=utf8mb4
            - --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
        volumes:
            - mysql_test:/var/lib/mysql/data

volumes:
    mysql_test:
```

Try running `docker-compose up -d --build` now. Both containers should spin up, with the `db` container starting up first, because `deepnatural-ai-api` has it as a dependency.

If you do not want to combine the docker-compose files. Please list out the running containers after you start them both up using `docker container ls`.

Comment: i add when i `docker container ls` thank you :)

Comment: Did you try changing the `HOST` setting in Django settings to `good-mysql` instead of `db`?

Comment: yeap i tried already but still failed :(

Comment: It seems to be a networking issue between the containers. Try removing the `ports` configuration in your `db` service?

Comment: I tried now, delete `ports 3307:3306` and  `docker-compose down` -> `docker-compose up -d` again but still doesn't work

Comment: Try rebuilding your image before testing. `docker-compose down` & then `docker-compose up -d --build`